# ffserver not viewable outside network

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I'm running ffserver/ffmpeg to stream a usb camera on my mac. Everything works as expected when I try to view the camera from inside my network but not when I try from outside the network. It works internally using either the DHCP assigned IP address for the mac or the ISP assigned external IP address.

If I try viewing when outside, the page appears to respond but asks for a log in, but I have no idea what is actually asking for the login - I've set up port forwarding on my router to forward requests to my mac. If I point an external browser at a different port I get nothing, so it appears that it's either the mac or ffserver that wants the password. I tried using my own login for the mac but that didn't work.

built-in firewall is disabled on the mac (running 10.13.2 - high sierra).

I used a basic ffserver config file from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/peterhellberg/ebfc72147c2009ee720aafe57ce9c141) although I changed the port to 8081.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out port 8081 is used by another service by default on the Mac. I changed it to a different port and it worked straight away.

Irritatingly it [isn't listed](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202944)

The best I could find documenting what actually lives on port 8081 is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003335/cant-package-react-native-because-of-port-8081-sunproxyadmin/33005583) suggesting that it's sunproxyadmin.

Comment: If it isn't listed, it would be nice know which service it is. Other people might run into the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer. Apparently it's the "well known" sunproxyadmin. *rolls eyes*